# In the 2003 anime FMA, what are the ingredients for making Homunculi?

Tags: fullmetal-alchemist-series, fullmetal-alchemist-2003

Referring to the 2003 anime FMA, what is the exact process to creating an Homunculus? I haven't watched the anime in a little while but if this makes sense I am looking for the ingredients that are put together to make an Homunculus in the 2003 anime.

I do remember that Edward used the composition of what the human body was made of but other than that I can't remember exactly what the ingredients (if this makes sense) on what Homunculi are created from.

For some reason I remember that you need the persons flesh that you are trying to bring back for human transmutation but cannot remember where I heard this from and I am pretty sure Edward didn't do this when he tried to bring back his mother.

If you don't get the question think about how a salad is made and think of it as if I am asking what ingredients go into it to make it a salad if this makes sense.

Answers are appreciated. :)

Comment: My general assumption is that it requires the ingredients used in human transmutation (though I'm not sure about Gluttony) - i.e. either the appropriate chemicals or the original body itself (which would of course contain the appropriate chemicals).

Answer (score 7):

I'd assume it be mostly the same with every homunculus since they are created from failed attempts at Human Transmutation which in most cases is bring someone back to life, that being said the Human Composition that can be brought with a child's allowance is probably the collection of ingredients that are used.

We can from the series confrim what was used as material for 2 of them, they are

- **Sloth** (Ed's and Al's mother) - the human composition Ed and Al read up on which during the process we hear Ed rep.
- **Wrath** (Izumi's child) - Izumi used her child's body as material and it was reborn as a homunculus (it was still wrapped in the sheets Izumi had it in)

as for the rest, i can only make these assumptions.

Gluttony was purposely created by Dante to use the Philosopher's Stone so he may have been created differently using different materials which would be compatible with the stone, in the movie he also shoots out Red Stones so *Red Water* may have been used.

Not sure about Pride or Greed on how they were made so it's not entirely sure what their Material was.

Lust was the lover of Scar's Brother and since he was a heretic already for doing Alchemy in the first place so he may have exhumed her body though it's never clear if he studied the same line of Alchemy Ed and Al used (Ishbal seems to have a similar thing to Alchemy which developed the Grand Arcanum to transmute a Philosopher's stone).

Envy was Dante's and Hohenhiem's son so we could assume the material for him was either his own remains or the same composition Ed and Al used for Sloth though there might have been something else in Envy which caused his transformation into a dragon when he passed though the gate (though this could have been because of his powers which he was using to try and get the game to take him to Hohenhiem)

Comment: Basically the general ingredients seem to be: the elemental composition of a person (including water, carbon, suphur, phosphorous, etc.) with in raw or corpse-liek form and living bodily material from the casters.  Is that correct?

Comment: @kaine bodily material from the Alchemist i don't know, we only see Ed and Al add blood to substitute the soul, Izumi didn't add anything else but the body of her child. the Elric's bodies and Izumi's Organs are more from the rebound of the unbalanced alchemy trying to balance itself and since we don't know the exact events of Envy's creation we don't know what the rebound was like with Dante and Hohenhiem or if they added any bodily  material

Comment: Ah. I assumed her organs and their bodies were unintentionally incorporated into the homunculus.

Comment: @kaine i'm not sure about that actually, it could make sense if Wrath;s organs were damaged and Izumi's was taken to repair them and Al's body was used to give Sloth Trish's from (Ed and Al put together the composition of the average human, there's about to be some variance for appearances).

Comment: this would also indicate the Ishbal version of Alchemy is different since Scar's Brother seemed to be fine after creating Lust maybe what was taken from him was sanity since he walks out naked with those tattoos near the end but Sanity isn't something that could be measured like body parts

Answer (score 3):

The human body composition you were looking for is detailed in a quote on a Wikipedia page.

> Water: 35 l. Carbon: 20 kg. Ammonia: 4 l. Lime: 1.5 kg. Phosphorus: 800 g. Salt: 250 g. Saltpeter: 100 g. Sulfur: 80 g. Fluorine 7.5 g. Iron 5 g. Silicon 3 g. and trace amounts of 15 other elements.

However, this excludes the part of the alchemist that is creating the homunculus.

[Click here](http://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Fullmetal_Alchemist_(anime)#To_Challenge_the_Sun_.28One_who_Challenges_the_Sun.29_.5B1.01.5D)
to see the full conversation between Edward and Rose.